# Rust is not honoring a custom cfg feature flag for conditional compilation

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use rust's conditional compilation feature and it is not working at all.   I'm attempting to use this to toggle between a default library and a different one, using the `cfg` to re-export one of two different submodules depending on if the feature flag is set or not.   The code:

lib.rs:

```
pub mod ffi;
#[cfg(ffiv1)]
mod ffiv1;
#[cfg(not(ffiv1))]
mod ffiv2;

#[test]
fn test_ffi_struct() {
    let _fs = ffi::FFIStruct{ x: 42};
}


#[cfg(ffiv1)]
#[test]
fn test_v1() {
    println!("v1 enabled");
}
```

ffi.rs:

```
//re-export as ffi::FFIStruct
#[cfg(ffiv1)]
pub use ffiv1::FFIStruct;

#[cfg(not(ffiv1))]
pub use ffiv2::FFIStruct;
```

ffiv1.rs:

```
pub struct FFIStruct {
    pub x: i32,
    y: IShouldFail
}
```

ffiv2.rs:

```
pub struct FFIStruct {
   pub x: i64
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[features]
ffiv1 = []
```

With the default `cargo build`/`test`, this builds and works as expected, everything is ok.

With `cargo build  --features ffiv1`, it behaves as no feature flags were passed at all.   Running `cargo` with --verbose shows `--cfg 'feature="ffiv1"'` going to `rustc`.

I would expect the compilation to fail on the undefined symbol `IShouldFail` in ffiv1.rs.  (and the extra test to run if it compiled).

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax for conditional compilation based on Cargo features is like this:

```
#[cfg(feature = "...")]
/* ... */

#[cfg(not(feature = "..."))]
/* ... */
```

In your case that would be `#[cfg(feature = "ffiv1")]`. The `#[cfg(ffiv1)]` also means something but is controlled by a different rustc flag than what Cargo uses for optional features.